# Mapping a Map type in Dataset to columns

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I have a UDF in spark which returns a Map output.

```
Dataset<Row> dataSet = sql.sql("select *, address(col1,col2) as udfoutput from input");
```

I want to append the values returned in the map to columns.

Ex - if the input table had 2 columns and the UDF map returns 2 key value pairs, then total 4 columns should be created with the Dataset.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
select 
    *, 
    address(col1,col2)['key1'] as key1,
    address(col1,col2)['key2'] as key2
    from input
```

Or use `with` to call your UDF only once:

```
with
    raw as (select *, address(col1,col2) address from input)
select 
    *, 
    address['key1'], 
    address['key2'] 
from raw
```

That would be the *hive* way.

In spark you can use all the *imperative transformations* (as opposed to declarative SQL) using `Dataset` API. In Scala it could look like this. In Java, I believe, it's a little bit more verbose:

```
// First your schemas as case classes (POJOs)
case class MyModelClass(col1: String, col2: String)
case class MyModelClassWithAddress(col1: String, col2: String, address: Map[String, String])

// in spark any function is a udf    
def address(col1: String, col2: String): Map[String, String] = ??? 

// Now imperative Spark code 
import spark.implicits._
val dataSet: Dataset[Row] = ??? // you can read table from Hive Metastore, or using spark.read ...
dataSet
  .as[MyModelClass]
  .map(myModel => MyModelWithAddress(myModel.col1, myModel.col1, address(myModel.col1, myModel.col2))
  .save(...) //wherever needs to be done later
```

Comment: I would rather do it the spark way. Can you provide an example of what you are calling the 'imperative transformation'?

Comment: @davyjones, I have added a Scala example to show what I mean by _imperative_ code.